# Adding a single Digit to a 4-digits long number in mysql

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to get a mysql script, that changes every 4-digit long number "into" a 5-digit long, by adding a "0" at the start of each number. This is, what I tried:

```
SELECT * FROM `customer_address_entity_text` WHERE CHAR_LENGTH(value) < 5;
SELECT CONCAT("0", CAST(value as CHAR(50)) AS value;
```

but it shows an error, that there is no field "value" found:

```
#1054 - Unknown field 'value' in field list (translated)
```

would be nice, if someone could help me with this.

(it also gives out this error, when I'm not trying to Cast 'value' to a CHAR)

tl;dr: I want '*value = "0" + value*' in mysql

example:
'value = 1234; value = "0" + value; value = 01234' and that in mysql

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two issues:

- There is a missing closing parenthesis for `CONCAT(`
- Your second `SELECT` has no `FROM` clause, so indeed there is no `value` field there.

So move that `CONCAT` expression inside the first `SELECT` clause and balance the parentheses:

```
SELECT c.*, CONCAT("0", CAST(value as CHAR(50))) AS value 
FROM `customer_address_entity_text`  c
WHERE CHAR_LENGTH(value) < 5;
```

If your purpose is to *pad* all values with zeroes so they get 5 digits, so that it also transforms 1 to "00001" and 12 to "00012", then use `LPAD`:

```
SELECT c.*, LPAD(value, 5, "0") AS value 
FROM `customer_address_entity_text`  c;
```

To *update* the `value` field:

```
UPDATE `customer_address_entity_text` 
SET value = LPAD(value, 5, "0");
```

Or, with your original `concat` version:

```
UPDATE `customer_address_entity_text` 
SET value = CONCAT("0", CAST(value as CHAR(50)))
WHERE CHAR_LENGTH(value) < 5;
```

Comment: Nice, thank you. Is there also a way to save it to the table? so that it saves the new 5 digit number to 'value'?

Comment: That depends. What is the data type of `value`?

Comment: It's a string, or what do you mean? sorry, I'm very new to mysql

Comment: You can see the data type in  the `create table` statement... So is it `varchar`?

Comment: It's 'text' i think, at least that's what's standing there

Comment: See addition to anwser.

Comment: And how would i save it with the `concat` function?

Comment: Just place the concat function in place of the `lpad` function, and add the `where` clause? Did you try?